# How do I securely fasten a sliding door floor guide?

Tags: doors, tile

I have a sliding door in a room with tile and it recently came off. I didn't realize it was just being held in by what looks like tape. What is the proper way to securely fasten the guide to the floor?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

These are designed to be screwed to the floor. [Install guide from the Orange Store](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/5e/5efd7af3-d040-4172-ae1d-f5af98846fb6.pdf)

Since your floor is tile, if using screws you'd want to mark the screw holes with the guide in position, then drill the holes carefully with a carbide-tipped bit just larger than the screw - the screw should not touch the edges of the hole at all to prevent the tile from cracking. Stop when you get through the tile, then switch bits to a regular bit, smaller diameter than the screw shank and drill a pilot hole into the subfloor. If the tile or mortar layers are especially thick, you may need longer screws than were included with the door guide to reach the subfloor.

You may be able to use an adhesive instead. Make sure whatever adhesive you try is listed for metal (the guide) **and** ceramic or porcelain (the tile).

Comment: Whichever (screw or adhesive) method you use, make sure you thoroughly scrape up the old double sided tape. If you use adhesive, use a cleaner to get all the old tape adhesive up off the tile, too. Leaving old adhesive behind will allow the new adhesive to fail sooner.